# BizTalk 2013 R2 Cumulative update 2 - not installing adapter pack update

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I'm trying to install the BizTalk 2013 R2 Cumulative update 2.
The BizTalk server part is installing correct, but asking for install pack for BizTalk Adapter Pack x86 and x64. I have already installed the LOB.

Can anyone tell why the CU2 is asking to "insert the Microsoft BizTalk Adapter pack disk and click OK", for the Adapter Pack x86 and x64?

Comment: Do you have Biztalkadpater pack x86 and x64 installed already

Comment: hi, Yes I have both package installed.

Comment: Have you tried providing it the installation media?  I'm not sure why it's asking, but why not just give it what it wants?

Comment: I just wondering why the Update is asking this on our bilztalk server in preprod environment. when i tried the Update on my dev pc it didn't asked for the adapter pack media. Both setup are equal!
I just wondering what the different could be?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's asking your for a CD/DVD is because you don't have the installation package for BizTalk 2013 R2 still mounted on your server. I had the same issue, and it stopped asking for a CD when I mounted the BizTalk installation .iso disc image onto the server I was installing the CU pack on. If you connect the installation software to your current BizTalk server, it will show in the DVD drive under My Computer. Re-running the CU installation afterwards will correctly install the updates. This has worked for both CU2 and CU6.